# Remove outliers using groupby in data with several categories

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series, vectorization

I have a time-series with several products. I want to remove outliers using the Tukey Fence method. The idea is to create a column with a flag indicating outlier or not, using `groupby`. It should be like that (`flag` column is added by the `groupby`):

```
date prod units flag
1    a    100    0
2    a    90     0
3    a    80     0
4    a    15     1
1    b    200    0
2    b    180    0
3    b    190    0
4    b    30000  1
```

I was able to do it separating the `prod`s using a for-loop and then making corresponding joins, but I wish to do it more cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I would compute the quantiles first; then derive IQR from them. Compute the fence bounds and call `merge()` to map these limits to the original dataframe and call `eval()` to check if the units are within their respective Tukey fence bounds.

```py
# compute quantiles
quantiles = df.groupby('prod')['units'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]).unstack()
# compute interquartile range for each prod
iqr = quantiles.diff(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)
# compute fence bounds
fence_bounds = quantiles + iqr * [-1.5, 1.5]

# check if units are outside their respective tukey ranges
df['flag'] = df.merge(fence_bounds, left_on='prod', right_index=True).eval('not (`0.25` < units < `0.75`)').astype(int)
df
```

[image: result]

The intermediate fence bounds are:

[image: fence]